# Google Charts me da error al traer consultas con un condicional vacio

Tags: php, postgresql, google-chart-api

Buenas tardes actualmente estoy trabajando con los gráficos de google chart y me funciona casi perfecto, estoy trabajando con un sistema de correos y quiero que me muestre una gráfica de los envíos que se han hecho durante el año, el problema es que si un cliente no tiene envíos durante ese año el sistema me arroja este error (y lo que realmente quiero es que si no tiene envíos todos los datos estén en cero):

```html
Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string
```

A continuación el codigo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
 google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
 google.setOnLoadCallback(dibujarGrafico);
 function dibujarGrafico() {
   // Tabla de datos: valores y etiquetas de la gráfica
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Mes', 'Campañas'],
     <?php
     $unavariable= $row = pg_fetch_assoc($result);
       if(isset($result)){
           while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)){
              $mes = "cualquiera";
             
             echo "['".$mes."', ".$row['cantidad']."],";
             }
       }else{
            $mes2="Cero";
            $nada=0;
            echo "['".$mes2."', '".$nada."'],";
       }
       ?>

   ]);


   var options = {
     title: 'Campañas año <?php echo $ano;?>',
     width: 900,
     height: 500,
     colors: ['#1a581b']
   }
   // Dibujar el gráfico

   new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
   //ColumnChart sería el tipo de gráfico a dibujar
     document.getElementById('GraficoGoogleChart-ejemplo-1')
   ).draw(data, options);
 }

</script>
</head>
<body>


<!-- Display the pie chart -->
<div id="GraficoGoogleChart-ejemplo-1" style="width: 800px; height: 600px">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yo que tu condiciono si trae datos que ejecute todo lo de google chart y personalizas para que no muestre el chart ni procese ese script.

Comment: Probé con esta condicional pero no funcionó: if ($result!=0 || $result != '' || $result !='null'){ . Estoy abriendo el condicional justo despues de que ejecuto el query.